# Reuse format string with sprintf

Tags: php, class, oop, extend, printf

I am trying to extend a class that uses a format string to replace attributes in an image tag. The format string looks like this:

```
protected $_tag = '<img src="%1$s" alt="%2$s" />';
```

It is used in this function:

```
public function getTag() {
    return sprintf($this->_tag, $this->_url, $this->_desc);
}
```

I extend this class and override the format string to accept some classes:

```
protected $_tag = '<img src="%1$s" alt="%2$s" class="%3$s" />';
```

Then I override the `getTag` function:

```
public function getTag() {
    $this->_tag = sprintf($this->_tag, '%1$s', '%2$s', $this->_classes);

    return parent::getTag();
}
```

Is there a better way than this to simply replace the one part of the format string? I'm having a hard time figuring out something more elegant.

Edit: The class I'm extending is not my own, so I can't modify `getTag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real nice way to do it, but you can simplify the code a bit:

```
protected $_tag = '<img src="%%1$s" alt="%%2$s" class="%s" />';
```

The first two directives have an additional `%` to make the first `sprintf()` skip them and the last directive has no positional argument, just `%s`.

This simplifies the code to:

```
$this->_tag = sprintf($this->_tag, $this->_classes);
```

Comment: I've tested this, so you probably left the positional argument in.

Comment: Oops, I must have. Works now!